# Learning storywriting - where to start?

Tags: storyboard

Over the years, games that affected me emotionally convinced me that storywriting is a very rewarding work.

Where could one start to get guidance for learning storywriting for games?
I haven't really done indepth storywriting for all my life though.

I thought about learning from novelists or screenplay writers.
But it seems the general consensus is that learning to write stories for games is a different animal compared to writing novels or screenplays.

**EDIT:**
The kind of story I want to write is deep and emotional, which may require years of practice.

Comment: I think this belongs to *Writers*...

Comment: It's specifically game story writing the OP is asking about.

Comment: Hello, and again welcome to Gamedev.SE. I'm sorry, but we are not a place to ask for links to how to get started learning how to do Gamedev tasks, including writing stories for them.

Comment: This Stack Exchange is for game development, not for general help learning how to write stories. Most people here are not writers, and most writing tips are not games-specific. For these kind of questions, you may find [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) more useful. If you have specific questions about writing stories _for video games_, those are welcome here.

Answer (score 6):

Well the basic principles stay the same with story writing as novels. One of the things that are very important in writing a screenplay is, you should develop a broader imagination on how to build a character and to what extent you wish for the character to be the focus of your/your audiences attention. I'd also recommend analyzing characters from games/movies..

Comment: Thanks for the input. Maybe I should give a go at writing stories and getting feedbacks from professional writers.

Answer (score 4):

I have a few links here:

- [Helpful tips for thinking about your story and the important points](http://www.whatgamesare.com/2011/02/video-game-writing-and-the-sense-of-story-writing.html). The video is not neccessary, but you should read the text.
- [Step by step to your story](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/gamestory3.htm)

In short words:

1. Grab your character.
2. Grab your main key in your story (for example, in Super Mario, "save the princess").
3. Grab your checkpoints and/or enemies.
4. Write your way to Rome.

Comment: Thanks, although I think this is for people who make more gameplay oriented games. In turn, the story for this type of games doesn't have to be so deep and epic. I'm more interested in games like Heavy Rain

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you read the book ["David Perry on Game Design"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/David-Perry-Game-Design/dp/1584506687). He brings up some important key points in compelling story telling, using the [Hero's Journey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomyth)  as example.